# Trapping Ctrl-C in ssh inside bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script that runs a SSH with some commands. If I `Ctrl-C` the bash script dies, but the ssh session (and its running commands) keep running. How can I effectively send the Ctrl-C to ssh session before dying my bash shell?

Comment: not a full answer, but read up on the `trap` bash builtin -- http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash -- `Ctrl-c` usually generates `SIGINT`.

Comment: To add to Rob Starling's comment, you might want to kill the whole process group (and you can easily find how to solve this age-old problem).

Answer (score 1):

This trap will send SIGTERM to all process in the process group when Ctrl-C is pressed:

```
trap 'kill 0' INT
```

It's worth noting that the ssh might leave jobs running on the other system, and that you can use a trap in the remote command to handle those as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could write something like that:

```
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
        echo "Pressed CTRL-C -> KILL SSH"
        kill -SIGINT $(pgrep ssh)
}
```

Comment: This might kill more SSH processes as you wish to kill.